# Angular directive intended to resize itself to match it's parent throws $digest() iterations error

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/IdJUCtLz41wkUsXPNvgK?p=preview

So I have a canvas directive, and I want the canvas to fill it's parent div. I tried to do it like

```
app.directive('paperBoard', function () {
    return {
      template: '<canvas></canvas>',
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var cv = element;
        var ctx = cv[0].getContext("2d");

        scope.boundsdim = function(){
            return {
                'width': element.closest('div').width(),
                'height': element.closest('div').height()
            }
        };

    scope.$watch(scope.boundsdim, function(nv,ov){
            ctx.canvas.width = nv.width;
            ctx.canvas.height = nv.height;
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

Problem is, this seems to go in some sort of infinite loop and angular throws an `10 $digest() iterations reached. aborting` error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from watching *by reference* to watching *collection contents*.

```
scope.$watchCollection(scope.boundsdim, function(nv,ov){
        console.log(nv);
        ctx.canvas.width = nv.width;
        ctx.canvas.height = nv.height-4;
    });
```

From the Docs:

> - Watching *by reference* ([scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) `(watchExpression, listener)`) detects a change when the whole value returned by the watch expression switches to a new value. If the value is an array or an object, changes inside it are not detected. This is the most efficient strategy.
> - Watching *collection contents* ([scope.$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) `(watchExpression, listener)`) detects changes that occur inside an array or an object: When items are added, removed, or reordered. The detection is shallow - it does not reach into nested collections. Watching collection contents is more expensive than watching by reference, because copies of the collection contents need to be maintained. However, the strategy attempts to minimize the amount of copying required.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- scope watch depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths).

Your `scope.boundsdim` function returns a new object each time it is called. Since `$watch` watches *by reference*, it was calling the listener function everytime.

Also your listener function was increasing the height by 4 each time. Changing to `ctx.canvas.height = nv.height-4;` stabilized height changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this issue with small changes to your CSS.

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
paper-board {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid blue 2px;
}
```

see the result at http://plnkr.co/edit/kSUFP8kDoYDJw9apVZ9a?p=preview

Comment: But the outer div cannot have a fixed width/height. It's supposed to be changing and the canvas needs to adapt itself each time.